# How do I get addresses of tokens held by a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, staking

My contract receives various types of ERC20 tokens. I'd like to know the addresses of the ERC20 tokens within the contract. The addresses are compulsory since they are still used within the contract.

There are other ways of doing this but it involves using some javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the EVM is designed doesn't permit you to query all tokens held by a contract. Technically, it is the token contract that stores users' balances.

The only way to keep track of all assets received by the contract is off-chain, through a web3 implementation.